# addEventListener in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a simple domain check before sending an email on gmail. So I wrote the below code:

```
//debugger;
document.addEventListener('blur', function(event){
var target = event.target;
if (target.name !== 'to' && target.name !== 'cc' && target.name !== 'bcc') return;
console.log(target.name, ":", target.value);
},true); // event listener blur
```

I can see target.name on console window like "to:","cc:", or "bcc:". However, can not get value at all. Any advice appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I see it without a problem when I put your code in the console. How do you inject that code into the page ?

Comment: This is script.js
`document.addEventListener('blur', function(event){
var target = event.target;
if (target.name !== 'to' && target.name !== 'cc' && target.name !== 'bcc') return;
console.log(target.name, ":", target.value);
},true); // event listener blur`

And this is manifest.json
`{
  // Required
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Checkers",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "content_scripts": [{
     "all_frames": true,
     "matches": ["http://mail.google.com/*", "https://mail.google.com/*"],
     "js": ["script.js"],
     "run_at": "document_start"
   }]
}`

Did I something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>(What I believe to be)</sub>

#### The problem

Each time you add an address in recipient's field (`to`, `cc`, `bcc`), a new input field is appended to the element holding the recipient address (e.g. with `name="to"` and `value=<email@addree.ss>`). Furthermore, an empty `textarea` is always appended at the end and its purpose is to capture any new email address you might want to add (convert it to an `input` field as mentioned before and emptying itself again).

Use case:

1. You see 3 email addresses in the `to` field.
2. You click in the field (so it gains focus).
3. You click away (so it losses focus).
4. The following gets logged: `to:`  (i.e. no value).

What actually happens, is that you log the value of the **empty** `textarea` at the end of the `to` field.

#### The solution:

Every time you catch a `blur` event related to a recipient's field, act upon (e.g. log) the values of all elements whose name equals the blurred field's name.
I know it doesn't make much sense, so here is an example:

```
document.addEventListener("blur", function(evt) {
    var tname = evt.target.name;
    if ((tname !== "to") && (tname !== "cc") && (tname !== "bcc")) {
        return;
    }

    var elemList = document.querySelectorAll("[name='" + tname + "']");
    [].slice.call(elemList).forEach(function(elem) {
        console.log(elem.name, ":", elem.value);
    });
}, true);
```

Comment: Oh, I see! You saved my life. now I understand why I was keep getting no value. Thank you very much!